# Azure dashbord for VMs?

Tags: azure, monitor

I want to create a design (UI) for a Azure  metricx dashboard for around 200 VMs, just like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/media/overview/dashboard.png
I need your help, so from your point of view, what are relevant information to display on a dashboard with that amount of VMs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getin into azure as well, +1